# Button Functions

Tags: python, tkinter

Fairly new to this python and GUI stuff(tkinter), been working on this for about 3 days and have exhausted my resources, all i want to do is click the "start" button and make my solenoid turn on and run, and click "stop" to make it stop......

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')                #size of window



class Cycle:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        myFont = font.Font(size=20)     #define Font


        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Start", bg="green", fg="black", command = self.printMessage,width=20, height=5)
        self.printButton['font'] = myFont
        self.printButton.pack()


        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text ="Stop", bg="red", fg="black", command =frame.quit, width=20, height=5)
        self.quitButton['font'] = myFont
        self.quitButton.pack()


    def printMessage(self):
        print("Well Done!!!")

root.mainloop()


channel = 21

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT)

def solenoid_on(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)   # Turn solenoid on


def solenoid_off(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)    # Turn solenoid off

if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            for i in range(2):        # Number of times ran is writen in ==> [range(put run times here)]
                solenoid_on(channel)
                time.sleep(1)         # Sets lag time
                solenoid_off(channel)
                time.sleep(1)         # Sets run time
            print("Cycles", i+1)

            GPIO.cleanup()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: When you call `root.mainloop()` the program enters a loop and won't execute the code after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the callbacks for the two buttons to the correct functions.

```
self.printButton = Button(frame,
                              text="Start",
                              bg="green",
                              fg="black",
                              command=lambda: solenoid_on(21),
                              width=20,
                              height=5)
```

and

```
self.printButton = Button(frame,
                              text="Start",
                              bg="red",
                              fg="black",
                              command=lambda: solenoid_off(21),
                              width=20,
                              height=5)
```

Then instantiate `Cycle` with

```
c = Cycle(root)
```

before starting the event loop.